# Why does this encrypted string have funny characters in it? It isn't readable?

Tags: c#, encoding, cryptography, rsa

I'm converting the encrypted text using UTF8, yet the resulting string has funny characters that I can't read and not sure if I can send this text to the browser.

```
        string message = "hello world";
        var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);

        var c = new UTF8Encoding();

        byte[] dataToEncrypt = c.GetBytes(message);
        byte[] encryptedData = rsa.Encrypt(dataToEncrypt, false);

        string output = c.GetString(encryptedData);

        Console.WriteLine(output);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

When I run the above, I get the following:

```
�VJI����J/;�>�:<�M����g�1�7�A.@�`J�s��~��)�Fn�����5�.���o���ҵ���jH3;G�<<��F�͗��~?�Y�#���j���6l{{�Y�$�]���nylz���X8u�\f�V1/�$�n+�\b��\b�fsAh՝G\n�\t���\b���6߇3����Ԕ���4��@هhI���'\0� T�n��|EϺ^7ú l��T\\!�w���QRWA%p��V\f��5�
```

I need to send this text back to the browser, or save it to a file and currently I'm not sure why I am getting these characters?

Comment: It is very important that you NOT use a text encoding to encode binary data!   You are guaranteed to lose data this way.  Encrypted data is binary data.  If data started out as a string and you encoded it to make it binary THEN and THEN ONLY you should use the same encoding to convert it back to a string.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you are taking an array of bytes that was not created by encoding text, and use it as if it was. You can only decode data that was created by encoding, if you decode any arbitrary data, you end up with garbage.

If you want the binary data produced by the encryption as a string, use for example base64 encoding:

```
string output = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData);
```

---

When you want to decrypt the data, use `Convert.FromBase64String` to get the byte array back, decrypt it, and use `Encoding.UTF8.GetString` to turn it back into the original string. There it will work do decode the data, because it was created by encoding the string from the beginning.

Comment: So I still use the UTF8 byte converter to get the bytes?

Comment: @user1361315: Yes, once you have decrypted the data you are back with what you encoded to start with, so for that you use UTF8.

Answer (score 3):

These two lines are pretending that the output of an RSA-encrypted UTF-8 sequence is a valid UTF-8 sequence:

```
    var c = new UTF8Encoding();
    string output = c.GetString(encryptedData);
```

But this is simply not the case: the RSA encryption maps byte values to other, (seemingly) arbitrary byte values. The resulting byte sequence doesn’t form a valid UTF-8 sequence (there is no reason to assume that it would), and thus cannot be treated as one.

If you merely want a readable (or HTTP sendable) representation of your data, then Base64 is the way to go, as shown in other answers. Fundamentally, though, you should probably read Joel’s article about [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: What insult? People aren’t born experts, and even experts still learn.

Answer (score 2):

Encrypting a string will result in a byte array that contains non-printable characters. You'll want to convert it to base64 to have a readable version of it.